# Simple Post Request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

It's my first post here, I'm trying to do this with Alamofire:

Swift code:

```
let name = "Taza"
let description = "50cl"
let parameters = ["name": name, "description": description]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://xxxxx.es/JSONpresenter.php?op=5", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON);
```

PHP code:

```
$op=$_GET['op'];

else if($op == 5)
{

    // Get user id
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : “”;
    $description = isset($_POST['description']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']) : “”;

    add($name,$description);

}
```

But only get a register with "" in all cells. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to set JSON encoding? put 'encoding: .JSON' after parameters

Comment: yes, but only insert a register with name = "", and description = "". Maybe php fail?

Comment: try to var_dump json on the server to see whats going on

Comment: i tried this on php but only insert a empty register foreach($_POST as $nombre_campo => $valor){ 
     $asignacion = "\$" . $nombre_campo . "='" . $valor . "';"; 
     eval($asignacion); 
     add($nombre_campo, $valor);
  }

Comment: Seems like you got isset false, you should try to check json u send and jaon you receive, i am not 100% sure how to check it in php

Comment: Finally i do the same but with .GET request, run ok but i would have preferred do with .POST

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the URLEncoding instead of JSONEncoding for this particular case